# How to use azure AD authentication from node.js server side non interactively

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I have configured azure AD service and an user in it and used react-adal to get the token, which worked fine.But now i need to change this flow and instead have my own login form and send the credentials to node.js express server and verify these from azure ad without a login popup from azure and store the returned token in the passport session.I have tried using node-adal but not sure how this can be achieved ,Can this be done? Are there any examples for this.Thanks

Comment: Do click on "Mark as Answer" on the post that helps you and vote it as helpful, this can be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @juunas, here is the non-interactive method([login with username and password](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-graph/latest/)) for your reference. This sample is used to manage MicrosoftGraph Resources.

```
var msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
 var graphRbacManagementClient = require('azure-graph');
 var tenantId='abcd-efgh-ijk-lmno-12345';
 // Enter your tenant ID here which can be found from your Azure AD URL
 // Eg. https://manage.windowsazure.com/example.com#Workspaces/ActiveDirectoryExtension/Directory/<TenantId>/users

 msRestAzure.loginWithUsernamePassword('username@contosocorp.onmicrosoft.com', 'your-password', { tokenAudience: 'graph', domain: tenantId }, function (err, credentials, subscriptions) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  var client = new graphRbacManagementClient(credentials, tenantId);
  var userParams = {
    accountEnabled: true,
    userPrincipalName: 'OfficialStark@<yourdomain.com>', //please add your domain over here
    displayName: 'Jon Snow',
    mailNickname: 'OfficialStark',
    passwordProfile: {
      password: 'WinterisComing!',
      forceChangePasswordNextLogin: false
    }
  };
  client.users.create(userParams, function (err, user, request, response) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(user);
    var userObjectId = user.objectId;
    client.users.list(function (err, result, request, response) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      console.log(result);
      client.users.deleteMethod(userObjectId, function (err, result, request, response) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
      });
    });
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, but you should not use it.
When using federated authentication, you should not be handling passwords.

The one way that works is a legacy migration path, named the ROPC flow.
However, none of these will work:

- User with MFA
- User synced from on-prem AD
- User with expired password

If you want to do something as the user in the background, have them login and store their refresh token securely.
You'd need to exchange the front-end access token for a back-end access token + refresh token.
Then you can use the refresh token to get new tokens for the user whenever.

Alternatively you can require application permissions to APIs and access them using client credentials from your API (client id + secret/certificate).